# How to get channel name in Youtube using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, youtube

[Youtube Channel Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54loJ.jpg)

Need to get the channel name out of this youtube channel page (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCutQjK5N6zIT-vXqXa4WI0A) , through C# Selenium

Comment: Attached is the youtube sample channel page

Comment: We're not a code-writing service. Please try something yourself first, and if you get stuck come back and we can help you fix _your code_. If you're new to the site (or if this is your first time asking a question), I recommend you take the [tour], read [ask] and associated help topics, and also read Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). In your case, we'll likely want to also see a [mcve] to show where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use Below Code

```
string ChannelName= WebDriver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='inner-header-container']//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-channel-name']")).Text.Trim();
```

Comment: why need so complex xpath? better to use css `#channel-header #channel-name #text`

Comment: i tried but it did not show 1 element with css selector